# One page application in the browser

Tags: web-applications

ich möchte eine Webanwendung schreiben. Da ich aber noch ziemlich neu in der Webentwicklung bin weiß ich garnicht wo ich anfangen soll.

[image: Web Application UI]

As I said, I have no idea how to start, so if someone can help me or tell me how to do something like this, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start simple by building basic static websites (not web applications) first so you get to know the absolute basics of HTML, CSS (and JavaScript) as well as HTTP (what it is and how it works).

Then you could move on to web applications and creating REST APIs. There are thousands of videos out there showing you how you could do this for pretty much any programming language you can think of. Start with one that you are already familiar with as this will be the easiest to get started and while the syntax and frameworks used might differ the concepts will be the same.

Popular languages to write backend/ server applications are Java, JavaScript/ TypeScript on Node, C#, Python, Kotlin or Go and last but not least PHP.
There are "very popular" frameworks for all of those languages:

- Java/ Kotlin: Spring or ktor
- Python: Flask or Django
- JavaScript/ TypeScript: express.js or hapi.js (not so popular)
- Go: Gin, Beego, Fiber
- PHP: Laravel

> This is by far not a comprehensive list but just the first that came to my mind.

Some YouTube channels and playlists you might wanna check out:

- [thenewboston: SpringBoot with Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJcshrJOnsE&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDPsneZWaOFg0H2wsundyGr)
- [TraversyMedia: Node.js & Express From Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_0ZzvHbNBQ)
- [CodeWithMosh](https://www.youtube.com/c/programmingwithmosh)
- [JavaBrains](https://www.youtube.com/c/JavaBrainsChannel/playlists)

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I'll look at the basics first, and then I'll look at web applications.